# error:: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, netbeans

I wrote a Java program but when I run it, it was showing:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:199)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:187)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:289)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:274)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:235)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:302)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:141)
        at lib.DP_CONNECT.connect(DP_CONNECT.java:47)
        at main.agent.main(agent.java:164).
```

I see other questions with same error and i try the solutions but the program doesn't work.

My tests (java version 1.4):

- Use Oracle's classpath (export CLASSPATH=..../ojdbc14.jar)
- Compile my program with path of library
  (java -classpath .:lib/ojdbc14.jar -jar AGENT.jar, i have put the library in directory lib)
- i try more solutions but program doesn't work.

I used these on server Unix with java's version 1.6 with ojdbc6.jar and the program run.

I don't upgrade the server.

Thanks
Francesco

Comment: What exactly is your execution command? and is the ojdbc6.jar present where you define it?

Comment: java -classpath .:lib/ojdbc14.jar -jar AGENT.jar. i can't use ojdbc6 because the java version is 1.4

Comment: Where in relation to the current path location is the `ojdbc14.jar`? Try `.:./lib/ojdbc14.jar`

Comment: I try this but i have same error.